# Error parser block with configtxlator Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.6

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have deployed fabcar example, with Raft consensus algorithm.

I ran `peer channel fetch` without problems.

I can see that the retrieved block is number 8, and that the information has been written to the file `mychannel.block`.

When I run the command "`configtxlator`" to be able to read the file in JSON format, it returns the following error:

> " error decoding: message of type %!s() unknown hyperledger
>   fabric"

Comment: Can you please paste the command you are running.

Comment: The file mychannel.block  was corrupted. Now, this command is ok.Thank Chintan Rajvir